# Is it possible to calculate Kolmogorov–Smirnov test as a calculated field?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset which containes several fields

I want to show the result of  Kolmogorov–Smirnov of each pair of fields.

- Is it possible to do it with tableau  ?
- or do I need to calculate the Kolmogorov–Smirnov outside of tableau ?

Comment: You can integrate Python or R with tableau so it's calculated outside of it but results are brought into your workbook. Check out TabPy https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2019/4/leverage-power-tableau-and-python-prescriptive-analytics-104906